# Vectorized comparison of values against a set of values

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a `pd.Dataframe` with a column that contains a value such as

```
df.iloc[:10]['occ']
Out[18]: 
0    4220
1     205
2    7630
3    8965
4     430
5    3930
6    4230
7    5620
8    4040
9    4130
```

I then have another dataframe with `start` and `end` values for different groups. I want to assign groups to the first dataframe based on their `occ` value.

```
       start   end
group             
10        10   950
11      1000  3540
12      3600  3655
13      3700  3955
14      4000  4160
```

Since these groups are not intersecting, we have a simple bijection. I was planning to for each `occ` value, take the group-index of the last row that is smaller than the said `occ` value.

```
testAgainst = np.repeat(dfGroups['start'].values[np.newaxis, :], repeats=10, axis=0)

array([[  10, 1000, 3600, 3700, 4000, 4200, 4300, 4700, 5000, 6000, 6200,
        7000, 7700, 9000],
       [  10, 1000, 3600, 3700, 4000, 4200, 4300, 4700, 5000, 6000, 6200,
        7000, 7700, 9000],
       [  10, 1000, 3600, 3700, 4000, 4200, 4300, 4700, 5000, 6000, 6200,
        7000, 7700, 9000],
       [  10, 1000, 3600, 3700, 4000, 4200, 4300, 4700, 5000, 6000, 6200,
        7000, 7700, 9000],
       [  10, 1000, 3600, 3700, 4000, 4200, 4300, 4700, 5000, 6000, 6200,
        7000, 7700, 9000],
       [  10, 1000, 3600, 3700, 4000, 4200, 4300, 4700, 5000, 6000, 6200,
        7000, 7700, 9000],
       [  10, 1000, 3600, 3700, 4000, 4200, 4300, 4700, 5000, 6000, 6200,
        7000, 7700, 9000],
       [  10, 1000, 3600, 3700, 4000, 4200, 4300, 4700, 5000, 6000, 6200,
        7000, 7700, 9000],
       [  10, 1000, 3600, 3700, 4000, 4200, 4300, 4700, 5000, 6000, 6200,
        7000, 7700, 9000],
       [  10, 1000, 3600, 3700, 4000, 4200, 4300, 4700, 5000, 6000, 6200,
        7000, 7700, 9000]])
```

And now, since the dimensions are `(10,)` and `(10, 14)`, there should automatic broadcasting happening. I am expecting to be able to do

```
df.iloc[:10]['occ'] < testAgainst
```

and get as a result

```
0  False False False False False False True  True  True  True  True  True  True  True 
1  False True  True  True  True  True  True  True  True  True  True  True  True  True
```

for the first two rows, because `4220` is larger than `4200` (and all numbers thereafter), and `205` is larger than `10`.

However, I get

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/foo/.conda/envs/myenv3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py", line 2881, in run_code
    exec(code_obj, self.user_global_ns, self.user_ns)
  File "<ipython-input-28-1bce7761846c>", line 1, in <module>
    df.iloc[:10]['occ'] < testAgainst
  File "/home/foo/.conda/envs/myenv3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pandas/core/ops.py", line 832, in wrapper
    return self._constructor(na_op(self.values, np.asarray(other)),
  File "/home/foo/.conda/envs/myenv3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pandas/core/ops.py", line 792, in na_op
    result = getattr(x, name)(y)
ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (10,) (10,14)
```

1. Why is the broadcasting not working here?
2. Given that this fails to work, what is the most efficient way to assign groups to my dataframe (real case: 10-15, groups, but 25 million rows in `df`).

Comment: Maybe something like `df.iloc[:10]['occ'].values[np.newaxis, :] < testAgainst` works.

Comment: Such broadcasting is not supposed to work, the trailing dimensions have to match or one of them has to be 1: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.broadcasting.html#general-broadcasting-rules. Either transpose or manually add a new axis.

Answer (score 1):

1) Reason the Broadcasting fails is because of the fact that `Series` objects form a 1-D labeled array *[shape=`(10,)`]* which is compared with a 2-D array *[shape=`(1, 14)`]*.

Let's consider: `ser = df.iloc[:10]['occ']`

If you had done:

```
>>> ser.iloc[0] < testAgainst
array([[False, False, False, False, False, False,  True,  True,  True,
     True,  True,  True,  True,  True]], dtype=bool)
```

This means if you could apply this same comparison to all the rows of the series, it would give you the right result.

```
>>> ser.apply(lambda x: x < testAgainst.ravel())
```

But, however this is really slow as it isn't vectorized and hence wouldn't be feasible to apply this to a larger number of rows.

What you can now do is to reshape the series in such a way that an extra dimension is inserted into it.

This allows NumPy to match the two shapes of the series `(10, 1)` and array `(1, 14)` respectively so that they can be compared via pairing in the respective dimensions.

2) More optimal solution could be:

```
>>> pd.Series((ser.values[:, None] < testAgainst).tolist())   # same as ser.values.reshape(-1,1)
```

Resulting output:

```
0    [False, False, False, False, False, False, Tru...
1    [False, True, True, True, True, True, True, Tr...
2    [False, False, False, False, False, False, Fal...
3    [False, False, False, False, False, False, Fal...
4    [False, True, True, True, True, True, True, Tr...
5    [False, False, False, False, True, True, True,...
6    [False, False, False, False, False, False, Tru...
7    [False, False, False, False, False, False, Fal...
8    [False, False, False, False, False, True, True...
9    [False, False, False, False, False, True, True...
dtype: object
```

***Note:*** Just one sample of the testing array is sufficient and you do not need to repeat this array to match the shape of the series object.